# How do I report a problem with the maps used for navigation in HERE Drive+?

Tags: maps, here

I was using the HERE Drive+ app the other day, and it wanted to divert me down some roads that I knew I could not get through. Is there a way to report faults in the map at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Map Creator](http://mapcreator.here.com/mapcreator/) tool to fix errors yourself. The edits will only be displayed in a "community" version of the maps until they are reviewed by Nokia and fully integrated into the Here database.

Comment: I added some annotations, but in the "my edits" list, it shows nothing, and there doesn't appear to be any confirmation email. Is there no way to do it "in-app"?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's possible. Have a look at the relevant FAQ entry: http://here.com/help/wp8/drive/feedback#wherecanireportproblemswiththe

Answer (score 2):

To report an issue with HERE Drive+ app, you can follow **[this link](https://mapreporter.navteq.com/#dashboard)**.

Comment: That site doesn't work for me - whilst you can sign up, it doesn't recognise the sign-in details.